# Flutter Firebase authentication errors

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm fumbling with my loginPage.dart. I upgraded the pre- 1.12 project.
This seems to be the last part of the migration

I made the errors bold within the code block

The Errors are:

> ‘User’ isn’t a function
> Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named ‘User’

Error:

> The getter ‘uid’, isn’t defined for the type ‘UserCredential’
> Try importing the library that defines ‘did’, correcting the name from all but one of the imports

Error:

> The name 'User’ isn’t defined in the libraries 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dar
> Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named ‘User’

Hopefully some one can help me out?

```
From firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1 to firebase_core: ^0.5.0
From firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3 to firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
From cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7+1 to cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
From firebase_storage: ^3.0.4 to firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
```

loginPage.dart

````
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import '../Models/appConstants.dart';
import '../Models/userObjects.dart';
import './guestHomePage.dart';
import './signUpPage.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeName = '/loginPageRoute';

  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _signUp() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String email = _emailController.text;
      String password = _passwordController.text;
      **AppConstants.currentUser = User();**
      AppConstants.currentUser.email = email;
      AppConstants.currentUser.password = password;
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignUpPage.routeName);
    }
  }

  void _login() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String email = _emailController.text;
      String password = _passwordController.text;
      FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      )
          .then((firebaseUser) {
        **String userID = firebaseUser.uid;**
        **AppConstants.currentUser = User(id: userID);**
        AppConstants.currentUser
            .getPersonalInfoFromFirestore()
            .whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, GuestHomePage.routeName);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 100, 50, 0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Welcome to ${AppConstants.appName}!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                          ),
                          validator: (text) {
                            if (!text.contains('@')) {
                              return 'Please enter a valid email';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          controller: _emailController,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (text) {
                            if (text.length < 6) {
                              return 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          controller: _passwordController,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _login();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 12,
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _signUp();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 12,
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The FlutterFire library was recently upgraded, which is probably where your problems come from.

1. The `FirebaseUser` class is now simply called `User`, which you should also see if you hover over the error in your IDE.
2. To get the current user, you no longer do `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`, but instead do `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` (so without `await` and without `()`).
3. The [`signInWithEmailAndPassword` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html) resolves to an `UserCredential` object. To get the UID, you do:

   ```
   .then((credentials) {
       String userID = credentials.user.uid;
   ```

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thank you for your input! This part seems to be fixed!

in the _signUp 
there is still an error on:
AppConstants.currentUser = User();

And similar in the _login()
AppConstants.currentUser = User(id: userID);

Hopefully you have a solution?
Where can I find documentation on this?

Kind regards,
Robert

Comment: Documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/, and the link in my answer. As far as I know `User() was not a built-in class before this upgrade, so it's probably a class of your own. My guess is that the new Firebase `User` class and your own existing class are conflicting. If that's the case, renaming your own class it the easiest fix.

Comment: Hi Frank, Sorry for my late comment!
You where wright, User was a class I made my self. I resolved the conflict. it is working now!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You miss to add `.currentUser()` before  `.uid` and jsut do this for all the other problems

But I hope to simplify you code just like that

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! FirebaseUser seems to be depreciated.

Do you have other suggestions?

Kind regards, Robert